# AngularJS provider return dynamic $get

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am wondering if it is possible or even wanted to have a provider return variables / functions dynamically?

I have been creating a plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/a9D6Fgdeag6sPsjpIGmy?p=preview).

What I basically trying to do is instead of returning `keys` in the `$get` method of the `MyLogProvider`, I would like to return everything without using `keys` with it.

So for example I would like to change:

```js
MyLog.keys.auth('This is going to be logged into the app:auth namespace');
```

To:

```js
MyLog.auth('This is going to be logged into the app:auth namespace');
```

Therefore I need to change the output of below dynamically by looping over all `keys`, is this possible?

```js
$get: function() {
  return {
    keys: keys
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but why don't you just return keys like `$get: function () { return keys; }`, without wrapping it in an extra object?

Comment: @MichaelRadionov can you create a working plnkr with what you are saying? Because I get errors when doing this.

Comment: Here it is http://plnkr.co/edit/R03j1ymnpoL51P6DgUJA?p=preview. I was not getting an output, because of undefined `debug` function, I've replaced it with simple `console.log`.

Comment: Here an updated with working `debug()`: http://plnkr.co/edit/a9D6Fgdeag6sPsjpIGmy?p=preview

Comment: It is very strange, but `debug` still does not work for me and there is no any errors, I've opened the updated plunker in an incognito tab in Chrome. Could you please post your error message?

Comment: In the `index.html` you should have `<script src="https://rawgit.com/visionmedia/debug/master/dist/debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: I figured it out, had to `debug.enable('app:auth')`, but still everything works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MichaelRadionov:

Change:

```
$get: function() {
  return {
    keys: keys
  }
}
```

To

```
$get: function() {
  return keys;
}
```

See next [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/a9D6Fgdeag6sPsjpIGmy?p=preview)